# Need a download manager for Ubuntu over network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, download, download-manager, file-download

I am trying to download a 22gb file over a slow vpn connection. The file is not hosted so what I did was just "connect to remote server" via Ubuntu, navigate to the directory where the file is and copy and paste it into my file system.

Unfortunately I was not able to download the file because the connection conked out. I was wondering if there was some sort of download manager that would enable me to copy the file I want and if the connection goes out again just resume.

Comment: "connect to remote server" could be FTP, but FTP SHOULD support resuming with a proper client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many swear by [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

Comment: wget -c specifically . I'm partial to axel myself, but every system has wget.

Answer (score 1):

You can try flashgot for Firefox: http://flashgot.net/features
There's kget if you use KDE
Or MultiGet http://multiget.sourceforge.net/
And Downloader 4 X aka d4x if you find it
Theses are graphical tools, otherwise wget is your friend, you can even continue an interrupted download!

Comment: does multiget and flashgot continue interrupted downloads?